# mathematica transpose does not work when using NumberForm and OutputForm

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, transpose

the code is like

```
nwwa = List["#w#"]; nkka = List["#ks#"];
 For[j = -4, j <= 4, j++,
     w = 16*(0.5 + 0.1*j);
     nwwa = Append[nwwa, w];
     //calculate ks
     nkka = Append[nkka, ks];
 ]
 Export["mathematica1.dat",Transpose[{OutputForm[NumberForm[nwwa, {3, 1}]],OutputForm[NumberForm[nkka, 6]]}], "Table"];
```

But I got the error:

"The first two levels of 
{{"#w#", 1.6, 3.2, 4.8, 6.4, 8., 9.6, 11.2, 12.8, 14.4}, {"#ks#", 
  0.28995, 0.1955, 0.14515, 0.1159, 0.09655, 0.0828, 0.07255, 0.0646, 
  0.05815}}
cannot be transposed".

the numbers are the values of nwwa and nkka.

If I just use

```
Export["mathematica1.dat",Transpose[{nwwa,nkka}], "Table"];
```

it works. but in the output file the values are like

```
3.200000000000003 0.19549999999999998
```

not what I want

```
3.2    0.1955
```

any tips?

Comment: Is there something missing from your error message? It looks as though it should read "The first two levels of MISSING cannot be transposed".

Comment: I add the missing part. Actually they are the content of nwwa and nkka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output formatting needs to be mapped over the results.

```
Export["mathematica1.dat",
  Transpose[{
    Map[OutputForm[NumberForm[#, {3, 1}]] &, nwwa],
    Map[OutputForm[NumberForm[#, 6]] &, nkka]}], "Table"];
```